# Compare two Excel cell values up until a set point/word

Tags: excel, vba, compare, cell

Baby is trying to create his first set of macros for Excel and has run into a problem that's probably caused by lack of vocabulary in VBA. I'm pulling a report into excel, and I've already set up a few basic macros that remove rows and columns I don't need based on values in cells or lack thereof, and I have sorted the whole report alphabetically based on the "description" column (Column E, if that matters). What I want to do next is where I'm hitting a roadblock; I want to go down column E, "Description", and I want to separate companies by adding in new rows between them.

Now, the company name isn't the only information in the description, so I only need to compare up until the word "job" to get the company name from cells E5 and E6 to see if they match, or if I add a row or two between them. If there's only one entry for the company, I only need one row added below it. If there are 2 or more entries for the same company, I need two rows added below that companies set of data. So, for instance:

| Description | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| ABC Company:Job#234-@Ory | 100 |
| ABC Company:Job#823-Dallas | 300 |
| Beyond Co.:Job#725 | 10000 |
| Beyond LLC:Job#154-AirCo | 200 |
| Beyond LLC:Job#155-AirCo | 2000 |
| Company X:Job#613-Todd @900 | 100 |
| Company X:Job#613-Todd @700 | 600 |

etc.

Would Become:

| Description | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| ABC Company:Job#234-@Ory | 100 |
| ABC Company:Job#823-Dallas | 300 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Beyond Co.:Job#725 | 10000 |
|  |  |
| Beyond LLC:Job#154-AirCo | 200 |
| Beyond LLC:Job#155-AirCo | 2000 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Company X:Job#613-Todd @900 | 100 |
| Company X:Job#613-Todd @700 | 600 |

etc.

This formatting would then let me auto-sum the amounts column per company later if there's more that one entry for said company, but I can work on that part on my own. The comparison between cells is my issue, I don't know how to compare only a certain part of a cell to a certain part of another cell when the amount of characters in each part could be wildly different between them.

So, I started by trying to use the same setup that worked for scanning and deleting rows based on specific cell content previously.

This macro was used to scan Column A in the report for a certain phrase and delete any row which had that phrase in Column A.

```
Sub DeleteKeyPhrase()

    Dim lastrow As Integer
    
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Range("A3:A" & lastrow).Select
    
    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Key Phrase" Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I was hoping at the start that I could use the same format of a loop on the description column, and my first attempt looked something like this:

```
Sub SepComp()

Dim lastrow As Integer
    
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Range("E3:E" & lastrow).Select
    
    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1
        If Not Cells(i + 1, 5).Value Like Cells(i, 5) Then
        Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Just to see if I could insert any rows at all, before setting up more conditions for 1 vs 2 rows. The macro ran and no error popped up, but nothing happened in the sheet. So, I started looking to see if there was a better way to compare cells contents other than "Like" and "Not ____ Like" or the = sign.

I've since learned that there are ways to select how many characters from the Left or Right of the string and compare those characters to each other, but that wouldn't always work here given the massive discrepancy between the length of certain company names. For instance, a character amount of 12 from the left would not split "Industrial Products:Job #123" from "Industrial Precision Equipment:Job #654" when it should; In turn, that criteria *would* split "VDMA:Job#154" and "VDMA:Job#423" when it shouldn't, based on what I need.

Recording the Macro using excels recorder tool seems pointless since it's following my selections based on cell reference/distance, not reading cell contents. It wouldn't carry over to the next report when companies change and the amount of lines differ.

Any guidance is appreciated here, I'm very new to VBA and only have a small background in any coding at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestood correctly the problem is in getting the name form the string.
You could try to use something like function below to extract the name from the cell:

```
Function CleanName(n As String) As String

Dim pos As Integer
Dim result As String

 

pos = InStr(LCase(n), ":job")
result = Left(n, pos - 1)


CleanName = result

End Function
```

Comment: You did understand correctly, Grabbing the company name without the job info is the issue. I like the look of this at first glance, I will play around with this and update you. I really appreciate the help, thank you so much!

Comment: Update: This worked great to parse out the text I needed! Thank you again!